# Generate reports in birt using user input. When input is null, everything should be fetched otherwise corresponding data should be shown

Tags: birt

I have to create a birt report with user input parameters. It is something like when the para
meter is left blank it should fetch all values from a table otherwise when the user inputs the students roll no.,the corresponding data should be fetched. Can this be done through Birt report? If yes, then please suggest a way.
Thanks!

Comment: i have found a way to do it using beforeOpen script on the data set. but still having a little problem with the parameter in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. If the parameter is optional you can't use the Dataset Parameter (with a ? in your query), because it will be null. Instead you have to modify your query using JavaScript.

Create a Report Parameter like usual, in this case 'stud_no'. Then add a comment in your SQL that you are reasonably sure is unique, I use something like --$stud_no$, wherever you want your clause inserted.

Then add a script like this to your Data Set, in beforeOpen:

```
if (params["stud_no"].value){
    this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("--$stud_no$", "and stud_no = " +  params["stud_no"]);
}
```

This replaces the comment with the clause when the parameter has a value. You can use regex in the search string, and then you can also insert it multiple places if you want.

Comment: Thanks @ebirkenes....while searching on google i stumbled upon this method only...solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Create your paremater using a like statement

```
 where students_roll_no like ?
```

Create your report paramater using as a text box, with a defualt value of %

Because the percent '%' is the SQL wildcard, it returns all values.  If the user enters a Student Roll number, it returns only that record. Additionally the user can enter 0500% and get all the records that begin 0500.

Comment: Alternative: where students_roll_no like coalesce(?, '%')

Comment: Another alternative: with params as (select ? as pattern from dual) select ... from params, my_table where (params.pattern is null or my_table.students_roll_no like params.pattern)