# Birt Report Multiple Input Parameter

Tags: eclipse, birt

My problem are same with this question

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453299/generate-reports-in-birt-using-user-input-when-input-is-null-everything-should)

I tried the solution at that question but it only work if all the parameter has value, but when there are no value the Birt Report output this error

```
The following items have errors:
Table (id = 4):
+ Can not load the report query: 4. Errors occurred when generating the report document for the report element with ID 4. (Element ID:4)
```

Can you guys help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example when the parameter has no value the query is not modified from what you put in the query text box.  You could also do something like:
1- put a query in like select * from mytable
2 - Then put a beforeOpen script like:

```
   if( params["myparameterval"] ){
       this.queryText = this.queryText + " where col1 = " + params["myparameterval"].value;
   }else{
       this.queryText = this.queryText + " where col1 = hardcodedvalue"
   }
```